# takari-lifecycle-plugin and lombok

Tags: maven

takari-lifecycle-plugin and lombok

[image]

Execution default-compile of goal io.takari.maven.plugins:takari-lifecycle-plugin:1.13.10:compile failed:  must be one of 'none', 'only' or 'proc'. Processors found:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.takari.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>takari-lifecycle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.10</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <!--                                <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>-->
                <compilerId>javac</compilerId>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <proc>proc</proc>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Where is your POM? Where is the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles on this, it worked fine for me in version 1.11.10.  all I needed to do was add the proc element to enable annotation processing.  In this case it was needed for log4j2.  Takari seems to have gone stale but there was some mention of making it work with lombok.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.takari.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>takari-lifecycle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.10</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <debug>${javac.debug}</debug>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            <source>${javac.source}</source>
            <target>${javac.target}</target>
            <proc>proc</proc>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```